# sub sub figure frame or box in latex

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, box, frame

I have two subfigures with common captions and the other two subfigures with common captions. I need something like the attached. where "abc" and "time(s)" are labels. Please help me to get the latex code.
Thanks and regards,
Sivakumar

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
      \frame{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{images/con_thd1}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{images/conv_thd2}}
        \caption{ MPC2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
       \frame{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{images/PROP1_thd1}
       \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{images/prop1_thd2}}
        \caption{MPC1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
       \frame{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{images/PROP_thd1}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{images/prop_thd2}}
        \caption{MPC}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Steady-state results }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Please share what you have tried so far for this.

Comment: please see the code included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

One way to achieve, what you after, is use `tikzpicture` to to add frames as well labels to images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=66mm, height=33mm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 6mm]
  \node[draw,
        label=below: time (seconds),
        label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left:abc}
       ] (fig-1)
       {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
  \node[draw, below=of fig-1,
        label=below: time (seconds),
        label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left:abc}
       ] (fig-2)
       {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
  
  \node[draw,inner sep=2em, fit=(fig-1) (fig-2)] {}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
       
  \caption{full caption}\label{fig:two-fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**
Your question is not very clear. We haven't any information, what contain your picture, is it graphic file or is drawn by help od some LaTeX package? it is unusual, that outside of pictures should be add labels. This should be (in nrmal circumstances) part of images, so I'm afraid, that your question is actually *XY problem*.

**Edit:**
Thank you for added fragment of code, which show what you do so far. However, here is desired to provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document which reproduce your problem. An example of MWE you can see above. This means, that you code fragment someone should extend to MWE, i.e.: add document preamble with loaded to problem relevant packages and `\end{document}` on the end of fragment.

Using my proposed solution in your code fragment is:

```
% \documentclass which one you use?
% existed preamble
\usepackage[belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}  % need to be added

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=33mm}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 6mm]
      \node[draw,
            label=below: time (seconds),
            label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left:abc}
           ] (fig-1)
           {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
      \node[draw, below=of fig-1,
            label=below: time (seconds),
            label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left:abc}
           ] (fig-2)
           {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};

      \node[draw,inner sep=2em, fit=(fig-1) (fig-2)] {};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{ MPC1}
  \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 6mm]
      \node[draw,
            label=below: time (seconds),
            label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left:abc}
           ] (fig-1)
           {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
      \node[draw, below=of fig-1,
            label=below: time (seconds),
            label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left:abc}
           ] (fig-2)
           {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};

      \node[draw,inner sep=2em, fit=(fig-1) (fig-2)] {};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{ MPC2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{full caption}\label{fig:two-fig}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. you have given only 1. (a) for me. I need 1.(b) also exactly same. and then the overall caption

Comment: please see the question again, i have edited the figure.

Comment: @SivaKumar, well, I focused on frame only. Other I left to you ... do you have problems to insert `tikzpictures` in `subfigure` environments? BTW, this is not site with services "we-do-your-task-instead-of-you" ... Please show us, what you try so far.

Comment: Thankyou so much @Zarko. I will check once. please see my code. i am unable to add code here. So, I have added  the code in the main question only.

Comment: @SivaKumar, looks here for questions tagged `subfigures` . Their answers will give clue/ ideas, how to insert my pictures in `ub-figures. BTWE, instead of saying "thank you", here is policy to upvote answer (for this so far you haven't sufficient reputation) and even accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer) if it solve your problem.

Comment: I agree. If you could see the code and say some changes, as per my question, then definitely I will upvote. thanks...

Comment: @SivaKumar, please, don't be arrogant. I'm not you employee nor assistant that you can condition your the rewards for my answer. I do not need your up-votes nor acceptances.

Comment: Sorry if i have hurt you. You saved my life. thanks...

Comment: also can you help me to remove the boxes for the inner subfigures.

Comment: just remove oprion `\draw` from inner boxes. Frankly, it's time that you read some introductory text about LaTeX (for example https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) and the Ti*k*Z package (for example https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)%E2%80%94Basic_Drawing, package documentation: first tutorial, part III) .